# Errors while compiling application

Tags: android, sdk

I have followed all the steps to create the file `main.xml` and `string.xml`, but I get an error when compiling my project. I tried using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and `Project -> Clean`...

```
[03/30/2013 11:24:52 - Asteroid] W / ResourceType (3827): Bad XML block: header size 2270 or total size 148813088 is larger than data size 0
[03/30/2013 11:24:52 - Asteroid] / home / syra / workspace / Asteroid / res / menu / asteroide.xml: 3: error: Error: No resource found That matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@ string / action_settings').
```

I would appreciate it if someone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

```
No resource found That matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@ string / action_settings').
```

Simply open `res/values/strings.xml` then add an element with the name `action_settings` and appropriate text.

```
<string name="action_settings">Settings for this action</string>
```

If you believe this already exists, double check the spelling of both names.

Comment: The problem is happening to me in the R.layout.main (main can not be resolved or is not a field)
and R.menu.asteroides (asteroids can not be resolved or is not a field).

Comment: Do you have these files in the appropriate folders? For instance `/res/layout/main.xml` and `/res/menu/asteroides.xml`